# httpException 11481611 caused from bad url... how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, web, httpexception, rd

In my event logs I am have an warning appear:

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
>   Date:          10/24/2011 11:14:18 PM
>   Event ID:      1309
>   Task Category: Web Event
>   Level:         Warning
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>
> Description:
>   Event code: 3005

Event Xml:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-10-25T03:14:18.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>18706</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>10/24/2011 11:14:18 PM</Data>
    <Data>10/25/2011 3:14:18 AM</Data>
    <Data>6076bff060b440559ee331b549fac246</Data>
    <Data>1629</Data>
    <Data>322</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-129637748517321437</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\</Data>
    <Data></Data>
    <Data>168</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool</Data>
    <Data>HttpException</Data>
    <Data>
      A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
      at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
      at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool</Data>
    <Data>555</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
      at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
      at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

My users are accessing an RD Web page from outside the network. I have recieved no reports of failure to access the page or launch the application, and I have tested it. The only thing is that I have noticed is that you will need to launch the application more than once to get it to run.

In order to access the RD Website users type https://rdwebpage.com

They see a web page with login box. The user logs into the web page
They see the published application, the user clicks on the application it launches the RDP login, the user sings in it looks like everything is working but the application does not launch.
The user clicks a second time on the application, follows the same steps and the application opens no issues.

It looks like the cause is the url being passed instead of the expected "https://rdwebpage.com"

I see:
" http://rdwebpage.com/https:/rdwebpage.com/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/default.aspx"

The result if you look at that web page is:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the 
exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).]
  System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +11481611
  System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +184

Version Information:
  Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
  ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

Any ideas would be helpful most of what I have seen on the web is passing characters but that is not the issue. I am not sure where the url is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be an improperly coded URL somewhere within the system. This can happen with web pages with links that the browser doesn't understand.

For example, if you had a link like this on this page

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com>Stack Overflow</a>
```

the browser would actually link to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911435/stackoverflow.com`.

Using your `http://rdwebpage.com/https:/rdwebpage.com/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/default.aspx` it looks like you could possibly be missing the second / after the original protocol.

Make sure that the link on the login page points to `https://rdwebpage...` and not `https:/rdwebpage...`